# Extract certain fields in a Json array based on a filter using JOLT

Tags: jolt

Please help. I am trying to extract certain fields from the below input based on some condition ( list of name and match whose key value is "key2"). But not getting the proper result.

**json Input:**

```
{"schemas": [
{
  "name": "myschema",
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "myname",
      "alias": "temp_alias",
      "keys": [
        {
          "name": "value1",
          "key": "key1",
          "match": "match_val"
        },
        {
          "name": "value21",
          "key": "key2",
          "match": "match_val2"
        },
        {
          "name": "value22",
          "key": "key2",
          "match": "match_val2"
        },
        {
          "name": "value3",
          "key": "key3"
        },
        {
          "name": "value4",
          "key": "key4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]
}

**Expected Output:** list of name and match whose key value is "key2".

```
{"key2": [
{
  "name": "value21",
  "match": "match_val2"
},
{
  "name": "value22",
  "match": "match_val2"
}
```

]
}

I have used the below spec but it is giving all the keys in output.

```
[{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "schemas": {
    "*": {
      "tables": {
        "*": {
          "keys": {
            "*": {
              "key": {
                "key2": {
                  "@2": "&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
]

Answer (score 0):

Check this spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "schemas": {
        "*": {
          "tables": {
            "*": {
              "keys": {
                "*": {
                  "key": {
                    "key2": {
                      "@2": "@2[]"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```